# Is it possible to inject subcomponent dependency into parent component?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

Consider I have the following object graph:

- Component called `AppComponent` scoped as `@AppScope` (`@Singleton` equivalent)
- Subcomponent called `SessionComponent` scoped as `@SessionScope`, which is a subcomponent of `AppComponent`

`SessionComponent` dependencies are being created (injected) at each session start.

Is it possible to inject `@SessionScope` dependencies (provided at `SessionComponent`) into `@AppScope` dependencies (provided at `AppComponent`)?

Vice versa is possible, as mentioned in `Component` documentation:

> The simplest way to relate two components is by declaring a `Subcomponent`. A subcomponent behaves exactly like a component, but has its implementation generated within a parent component or subcomponent. That relationship allows the subcomponent implementation to **inherit the *entire* binding graph from its parent** when it is declared.

I found that programmatically it is possible using [this approach](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/369), but is it possible to do using only Dagger API?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't:

> Bindings that are installed into a component can not see bindings from its subcomponent. Instead, it's the other way around: bindings in a subcomponent can depend on bindings in a parent component.

as stated in this [answer](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/369#issuecomment-232178082) from your link.